# How can I change status code in viewer-response Cloudfront event?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront, aws-lambda-edge

I want to secure Cloudfront response using S3 object metadata and some role data in DB (or some remote service), specif for current user. I think I should use `viewer-response` event here, to have access to S3 data and user data together. I try to set `status` and `statusDescription` in `response` object, but it does not work for `viewer-response` event, works for all other events. Setting headers still works.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const response = event.Records[0].cf.response;
  const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
  const isUserAllowed = await allowedByTokenAndDb(request);
  const isS3ObjectAllowed = response.headers['x-amz-meta-isSecure'][0].value === 'true';

  if (!isUserAllowed || !isS3ObjectAllowed) {
    response.status = '403'; // does not work
    response.statusDescription = 'Nothing';
  }

  response.headers['X-Powered-By'] = [{  // works, header will be added
    key: 'X-Powered-By',
    value: 'lol',
  }] 

  return response;
}
```

Is there any way to make `viewer-response` return another status? AWS documentation does not tell that it is possible or not. Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: Does it always return 200 Ok instead of 403 ?  403 is cachable in cloudfront, unless you override it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, it looks like you can only change responses in `viewer-request`, `origin-request`, and `origin-response` event handlers. This page doesn't explicitly state you CAN'T change the response in `viewer-response` event handler, but it does imply that since it only talks about the other three as being supported: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-updating-http-responses.html

Like you, I also couldn't get it to work, but I ended up using `origin-response` to meet my needs.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change status code, body
and a set of headers according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html

Specifically, it says

> Edge functions for viewer response events cannot modify the HTTP
> status code of the response, regardless of whether the response came
> from the origin or the CloudFront cache.

Answer (score 0):

Follow official documents: [Restrictions on edge functions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/edge-functions-restrictions.html#edge-function-restrictions-all)

> CloudFront does not invoke edge functions for viewer response events when the origin returns HTTP status code 400 or higher.

Hence, the function is not working.